# Issue: SVG <use> Element is Converted to String in XSL Template

Tags: xslt, svg, xlink

I'm fairly new to XSL, XPATH etc. Some of this code is mine, some are someone else's.

**Problem:** When the template below gets called with the templates I've outlined further below, all the `xsl:text` nodes after the if test is output as a string instead of an HTML node, and thus the icon is not rendered.

This question has to do with understanding the *why?* of what's going on. My exact question is at the bottom of this post.

So, I have a template that I call that generates SVG elements with a `<use>` element for use with an SVG sprite.

```
<xsl:template name="svg-link">

  <xsl:param name="svg-id"/>
  <xsl:param name="svg-class"/>
  <xsl:param name="svg-title"/>

  <span class="{$svg-class} svgstore svgstore--{$svg-loc}">
    <svg>
      <xsl:if test="$svg-title != ''">
        <title><xsl:value-of select="$svg-title"/></title>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;use xlink:href="</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('#', $svg-loc)" />
      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">"&gt;&lt;/use&gt;</xsl:text>
    </svg>
  </span>

</xsl:template>
```

All sorts of templates call/apply this template. There is one in particular that I'm having an issue with. We have two snippets implemented by the CMS that output the same markup, but the configurations for the snippets are implemented differently, i.e. Page Template A vs Page Template B. The snippet in question is made of multiple XSL templates. The templates are organized like so:

- **Snippet Template:** entry point for snippet for all callers. Accepts a couple of params related to CSS classes. Creates a few wrapper elements for the snippet. Calls the following template.
- **"Model" Template:** is a template that needs to be defined by each page template. As mentioned above, each page template uses a different approach to implementing configuration options for the snippet. The idea is to make the following template agnostic about how the snippet was configured in the first place because this template is responsible for knowing those details and passing it on to the following template.
- **Snippet Item Template:** renders most of the markup for the snippet based on the info passed to it by the *"Model" Template*.

Here's some simplified pseudo-code demonstrating above:

```
<xsl:template name="snippet">

  <xsl:param name="outer-classes"/>
  <xsl:param name="inner-classes"/>

  <xsl:variable name="items">
    <xsl:call-template name="snippet-model"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <!-- Render Snippet if it has content. -->
  <xsl:if test="count( $items )">
    <div class="{ $outer-classes }">
      <div class="{ $inner-classes }">
        <xsl:copy-of select="$items">
      </div>
    </div>
  </xsl:if>

</xsl:template>

<!-- Placeholder. Defined by each page template. -->
<xsl:template name="snippet-model"/>

<xsl:template name="snippet-item">

  <xsl:param name="a"/>
  <xsl:param name="b"/>
  <xsl:param name="b"/>

  <div class="snippet-item {$a}">

    <xsl:apply-templates select="$b"/>

    <xsl:call-template name="svg-link">
      <xsl:with-param name="svg-id">alpha</xsl:with-param>
      <xsl:with-param name="svg-class">alpha</xsl:with-param>
      <xsl:with-param name="svg-title">The Title</xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </div>

</xsl:template>
```

And an example of how a page template uses the above:

```
<xsl:template match="table[@class = 'snippet-alpha']">

  <xsl:call-template="snippet">
    <xsl:with-param name="outer-classes">page-template-a other</xsl:with-param>
    <xsl:with-param name="inner-classes">some-template-modifier</xsl:with-param>
  </xsl:call-template>

</xsl:template>

<!-- Template definition of `snippet-model` template. -->
<xsl:template name="snippet-model">

  <!-- Another page template might not use `tbody/tr` to loop over. -->
  <xsl:for-each select="tbody/tr">
    <xsl:call-template="snippet-item">
      <xsl:with-param name="a" select="td[1]"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="b" select="td[2]"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="c" select="td[3]"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
```

I've narrowed down my issue to likely be the `xsl:variable` capturing the results of `xsl:call-template` in the `snippet` template. And/Or the referencing of that variable later with `xsl:copy-of`.

### What Have I Tried?

Below I have *working* and *non-working* solutions, all of which I do not fully grokk why they may or may not work.

- **Works:** Adding `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"` to `xsl:stylesheet` for the file that contains the `svg-link` template and then modding `svg-link` template, see code below this list.
- **Works:** Instead of outputting the value of the `xsl:variable` that captures the results of `xsl:call-template` with `xsl:copy-of`. I replace `xsl:copy-of` with a second `xsl:call-template` that is identical to that of the call that was done inside the variable.
- **Does Not Work:** Used `xsl:sequence` instead of `xsl:copy-of`.
- **Does Not Work:** Tried data typing(?) the `xsl:variable` that captures the results of `xsl:call-template` with the `as` attribute. I.e. `as="node()*"`.

```xsl
<xsl:template name="svg-link">

  <xsl:param name="svg-id"/>
  <xsl:param name="svg-class"/>
  <xsl:param name="svg-title"/>

  <span class="{$svg-class} svgstore svgstore--{$svg-loc}">
    <svg>
      <xsl:if test="$svg-title != ''">
        <title><xsl:value-of select="$svg-title"/></title>
      </xsl:if>
      <use xlink:href="{concat( '#', $svg-loc )}"></use>
    </svg>
  </span>

</xsl:template>
```

**Question:** Why are some of the contents of the `svg-link` template being output as a string (instead of HTML) based on how the result of a call to `xsl:call-template` is captured/called? As you can see, I have working and non-working solutions - I would like to know why. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you trying to create elements with `xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"`, why can't you create the `use` element as a literal result element? In general, `disable-output-escaping` is an optional serialization feature for final result trees, it does not work inside of any variable.

Comment: Good question. That is something that someone else authored. And since I'm new to XSL, something like that wouldn't cross my radar.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, so the answer to why it's output as a string would be: _"In general, disable-output-escaping is an optional serialization feature for final result trees, it does not work inside of any variable."_ And the solution would be to do what I had attempted in the first list item under _What Gave I Tried_?

Comment: Yes, only I am not sure given that you explicitly mentioned it, that you didn't use the literal result element (together with some namespace declaration for  XLink namespace the attribute is from). So you seemed to know how to create the element node, only that seemed to have failed (don't know why, many try to use `xsl:value-of` on such variables and then it fails, but with the `xsl:copy-of` I don't see how that approach could have failed).

Comment: I just reviewed what I posted, and I see that I the first two items in the _What Have I Tried_ look like I was suggesting they did not. When, in fact, that list is a list of all attempts (working, non-working) but, as mentioned in the post, wanted to know why. And that appears to be the use of `disable-output-escaping`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `disable-output-escaping` is an optional serialization feature. Additionally, the XSLT 2 or 3 specs spell out when it doesn't work at all, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#disable-output-escaping

> If output escaping is disabled for an `xsl:value-of` or `xsl:text`
>   instruction evaluated when temporary output state is in effect, the
>   request to disable output escaping is ignored.

and https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#dt-temporary-output-state

> xsl:variable, xsl:param, xsl:with-param, xsl:function, xsl:key,
>   xsl:sort, xsl:accumulator-rule, and xsl:merge-key always evaluate the
>   instructions in their contained sequence constructor in temporary
>   output state

So inside your `xsl:variable` any `disable-output-escaping` can't work.

The whole attempt to use it to try to construct an SVG `use` element is completely unnecessary, you can create any result elements as literal result elements e.g. `<use xlink:href="{concat( '#', $svg-loc )}"></use>` (with an appropriate XLink namespace declaration in scope for the attribute from that namespace), or, if you need to compute part of the name or namespace, using `xsl:element`.

Comment: I think I may have a theory as to why the author of the `svg-link` template was using `disable-output-escaping` to create an SVG `use` element. They may have been trying to omit the `xmlns:link` namespace definition every time they created a `<use>` element. Since `svg-link` is creating SVGs that reference an SVG sprite that is included after the opening `<body>`, which has `xmlns` and `xmlns:xlink` namespaces defined on the SVG sprite, it may not be necessary to define `xmlns:xlink` over an over again?

Comment: Is it possible to create `<svg><use xlink:href="#id"/></svg>` without XSLT having to apply `xmlns:xlink` to an element of the `svg-link` template?

Comment: It depends on what you mean with "create": XSLT works with nodes based on namespaces so you can't create an element with an attribute having a prefix in its name without having a namespace declaration binding that prefix to a namespace URI. So while you work with nodes you can't create an attribute or an element having a qualified name with a prefix. If you want to create plain text output that has that string `<svg><use xlink:href="#id"/></svg>` then that is of course possible. But mapping nodes to that text output requires some custom serialization.

Comment: By _create_, I mean creating nodes/html instead of a string. When looking at the modified `svg-link` template at the bottom of my question, I originally had the `xmlns:xlink` namespace defined on `xsl:stylesheet`. This worked but appended `xmlns:xlink` namespace to the `<span>` element. I've since modified this so that `xmlns:xlink` is defined on `<svg>`. Thanks for all your help and clarifications as I get up and running with XSL/XSLT.